# Accessing current iteration of array object properties and populating fields

Tags: angularjs, html

I am attempting to iterate through an incoming data object with ng-repeat:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="(contractIndex,contract) in contracts">
    {{contracts}}
    <tr>

        <td class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
                <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-model="itemSearch.contract" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxOptions(14, 413, itemSearch.contract, 'searchContractOptions', $event)" />
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
                    <li data-ng-repeat="name in searchContractOptions" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeData('contract', name)">{{name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="true" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[3].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[3]"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @*<div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="true" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[4].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[4]"></div>*@
            <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="true" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[3]"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="9" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[1].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[1]"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="9" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[2].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[2]"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="20" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[5].htmlName)" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contract.fields[5]"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeContract(contract, contractIndex)">Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-show="issueContract(contractIndex)">
        <td colspan="7">
            <label class="error" data-ng-repeat="issue in contract.issueMessage">{{issue}}</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I know the data is coming through because {{contracts}} prints my object:

```
{"MEMBER_ID":"388","DATE_EFFECTIVE":"Feb 22 2017 7:47PM","DATE_END":"Feb 22 2017 7:47PM","FORM_COMPLETE":"True","CONTRACT_NUMBER":"b5v5b5b5bb5","SUPP_NUMBER":"A180","SUPP_NAME":"ABBOTT NUTRITION"}
```

First of all, how do I access the current iteration of contracts? Using                     `{{contracts.MEMBER_ID}}` prints nothing but `{{contracts[0].MEMBER_ID}}` does.

Then, when I do have access to the specific object array that is being iterated though, how do I display it on my fields so that they will repeat and show automatically?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Interpolating `contracts` shows the variable is an object, not an array. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you talking about `$index`?

Comment: @nicooga It is an array of objects, there is only 1 currently. Check edit and image for reference.

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro Do you mean like this? {{contracts[$index]}}. This doesn't print the object on the page.

Comment: What exactly is the type of `contracts`? The format "(key, val) in var" is used when iterating over an object's properties.

Comment: @nicooga There is a lot going on in contracts but I want what is inside                     {{contracts[i].UpdatedAsoc}}. Within UpdatedAsoc are just 6 string variables.

Comment: @nicooga Actually, the items being printed when I use {{contracts[0]}} is what I need {"MEMBER_ID":"388","DATE_EFFECTIVE":"Feb etc

Comment: Please, create [a gist](https://gist.github.com/) of the `contracts` data and attach it to this question. It really depends on the structure of your data which is now obvious from your post.

Comment: @SlavaFominII I'm not sure I understand. The data I need to work with is in the object/json string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using {{contracts}} it's referring to the list as a whole, so even when you are in the repeat selecting the {{contracts[0].Id}} it is only selecting the Id for the contract in position 0

what I would recommend is use your repeat as follows (shortened for ease of example)

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
            <tr>
                 <td class="text-center">
                    <div>{{contract.NameField}}</div>
                </td>
```

in this example the ng-repeat iterates through the list of contracts for you, you would use the contract as the singular contract in the iteration. As it iterates for each contract in the list it will show the object NameField for each contract. if each contract had a list of fields rather than named objects as shown in your example you could nest them like this.

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="field in contract.Fields">
                 <td class="text-center">
                    <div>{{field.Value}}</div>
                </td>
```

And this would iterate through the fields in your contracts, showing a table for each contract and a row for each field in each table.

If you were to name your fields ie. ID, Name, Company, Address, Phone etc. you could format each table and rather than iterating through each field you could show a nice UI and make each table kind of look like the contract you are showing. In that scenario I would recommend the first example.

As to your specific question, using the first example you would use

```
{{contract.MEMBER_ID}}
```

and allow the ng-repeat to iterate for you.

Comment: Awesome info but when I try: '<tbody data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts">{{contract.NameField}} ...' Nothing prints out for me.

Comment: I used NameField as an example if that's not an object on your contract object it wouldn't show, sorry. Have you tried using {{contract.MEMBER_ID}} ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't clarify. contract.MEMBER_ID doesn't work.